# Dependency injection question / small example problem

Tags: javascript, node.js, dependency-injection

Can simple vanilla dependency injection, such as modules exporting a function that expects an object of dependencies fix the below problem of helper files trying to share their helper functions with each other? Thanks.

`index.js`

```js
const { sumEvens } = require("./math");

const nums = [1, 2, 1, 1, 2];

console.log(sumEvens(nums));
```

`math.js`

```js
const { removeOdds } = require("./filters");

const isEven = (n) => n % 2 === 0;

const sumEvens = (nums) => removeOdds(nums)
  .reduce((sum, n) => sum + n, 0);

module.exports = {
  isEven,
  sumEvens
}
```

`filters.js`

```js
const { isEven } = require("./math");

const removeOdds = (nums) => nums.filter((n) => isEven(n));

module.exports = {
  removeOdds
}
```

`TypeError: isEven is not a function`, I think because of some circular requiring?

Comment: are you restricted to use `require`? can you switch to `import` syntax? if i understand correctly, that should resolve this issue.

Comment: I tried that actually via `package.json` `"type": "module"` (no webpack) and it still seemed to be an issue but maybe with webpack it will work. Thanks.